# InstallShield 2012: need to show oracle connection dialog instead of SQL Server

Tags: oracle, installshield

I need to have my InstallScript MSI project be able to display either a SQL Server connection dialog or an Oracle connection dialog. There does not seem to be an out of the box Oracle dialog for InstallScript (unbelievable). Any ideas on what that dialog should look like and how to only show one?